# What is the minimum amount of data I need to sign a file?

Tags: pgp, digital-signature, openpgp

Let's say I have a multi-gigabyte file on a **work** computer, and (2) I have my private GnuPG key on my **home** computer. I want to sign the really big file with my private key.

I trust my **home** computer completely.

I trust the **work** computer to  certain degree, I trust that there is no malicious code running on it at the moment, I trust there is no one fiddling with the hashing functions, and I trust the network connection between **work** and **home** is secure and un-altered. What I **do not** want to do is save my *very valuable* private key on the **work** computer, not even temporarily.

I also do not want to spend 4 hours transmitting the really big file over the internet from **work** to **home**. What is the *minimum amount of data* I need to send between the **work** and **home** computers in order to sign the file with my private key?

---

What I'm trying to figure out is if all PGP does is sign the hash of the file, is it possible for me to hash the file on the **work** computer, and then send the hash (along with any other required metadata) to the **home** computer to be signed, transparently, as if I actually had the file in hand?

SSH has agent forwarding features. Is there a similar feature already in GnuPG, or would I need to modify the source code if I wanted to create something like this?

Comment: Only the private key can sign the file.  So if your not willing to transfer the file to the environment with the private key and your not willing to transfer the private key to the environment with the file you have no other options.

Comment: @Ramhound No, the private key signs the hash of the file (which is comparably tiny), along with some other data, not the file itself.

Comment: You literally used the words "i want to sign the really big file with my private key" I am sure you are right.  I appreciate your feedback and will take it into consideration in the future.

Answer (score 1):

All you actually need is the proper hash sum of the file, but I'm not aware to make GnuPG or any other implementation creating a signature from a hash sum instead of a file (without modifying the source code).

But I can propose a reasonable alternative: **use OpenPGP smart cards**, like issued by the [FSFE as membership card](https://fsfe.org/fellowship/card.en.html) and also available to buy, or a [YubiKey Neo](https://www.yubico.com/products/yubikey-hardware/) capable of OpenPGP (which simulates an OpenPGP smartcard). With such a card connected to your work computer, you will be able to perform cryptographic operations using the private key stored on the card without this private key ever leaving that device. The card contains its own cryptographic processor, will receive the file's hash and return the signature back to the computer.